# unordered list is not displayed in IE6

Tags: html, css, jsp, css-float, html-lists

I have a JSP page with an unordered list which does not display at all in IE6, while it displays perfectly in Mozilla Firefox.

My JSP is:

```
<div id="topnav">
      <ul>
        <li class="active"><a href="index.jsp">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="AboutUsServlet">About US</a></li>
        <li><a href="ContactUsServlet">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PRODUCTS</a>

          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">LAPTOP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">NOTEPAD</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PALMTOPS</a></li>
          </ul>

 </li>
        <li class="last"><a href="#">SERVICES</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS for this is:

```
#topnav{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:660px;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    font-size:13px;
    font-weight:normal;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#000000;
    }

#topnav ul, #topnav li{
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    }

#topnav li a:link, #topnav li a:visited, #topnav li a:hover{
    display:block;
    margin:0;
    padding:15px 20px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#000000;
    }

#topnav ul ul li a:link, #topnav ul ul li a:visited{
    border:none;
    }

#topnav li.last a{
    margin-right:0;
    }

#topnav li a:hover, #topnav ul li.active a{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#059BD8;
    }

#topnav li li a:link, #topnav li li a:visited{
    width:150px;
    float:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:7px 10px;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#000000;
    }

#topnav li li a:hover{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background-color:#059BD8;
    }

#topnav li ul{
    background:#FFFFFF;
    z-index:9999;
    position:absolute;
    left:-999em;
    height:auto;
    width:170px;
    border-left:1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-bottom:1px solid #FFFFFF;
    }

#topnav li ul a{width:140px;}

#topnav li ul ul{margin:-32px 0 0 0;}

#topnav li:hover ul ul{left:-999em;}

#topnav li:hover ul, #topnav li li:hover ul{left:auto;}

#topnav li:hover{position:static;}

#topnav li.last a{margin-right:0;}
```

I googled and found out that by removing `float:left;` this works and placing `display:block;` will work for me. But it still is not working. I even tried `overflow:hidden;` but then too it does not work. I work in Eclipse and its browser is set to IE6 by default.

Comment: Respect to all the poor souls still having to develop for IE6.

Comment: You have our condolences.

Comment: @DanielLisik cant help it until our superiors understand this.

Comment: ie6 is no longer supported so how come you are still coding for it?  Try adding `height:0;` to the parent container of the item that isn't showing, you will need to use this as an ie6 only hack though otherwise it will break your layout in all other browsers

Comment: Have you tried it on IE8 or above?

Comment: @Braj no. U thik it will work there?

Comment: @user3349720 show this to your superiors: http://www.modern.ie/en-us/ie6countdown Unless you're from China, I would say you're entitled to not develop for IE6.

Comment: thank u for all the comments its better i start using a higher version. will try on that and get back to you.. thank u all

Comment: having to develop for IE6 is like manufacturing cars with coals in mind: what if someone tries to use coal as fuel? We have to keep that in mind, so make a separate tank for coal.. Argh!